# Determine affected file given logical block number

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, io, disk

Given the logical block number from these log lines in /var/log/messages, is there a way to determine what file was affected?

```
...Buffer I/O error on device sdd1, logical block 203953715
...lost page write due to I/O error on sdd1
```

Comment: @jasonwryan I think you're right assuming `logical block` means the same thing as `sector`

Comment: Does this help? http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37119/28489 - e.g.: `sudo debugfs /dev/sdd1` then `icheck 203953715` and use the indicated inode number (NNN) to do `ncheck NNN` ...