# Dmesg reports a lot of "Unrecovered read errors" and yet rsync copies just fine. Why?

Tags: rsync, hard-disk, io, dmesg

I've been copying moderately valuable data (nice to have, not the end of the world if it is lost) from a bunch of old HDDs to my new NAS with more reliable storage.

During reading I get a bunch or errors (which isn't exactly unexpected, as the disks are old) like this in my `dmesg` output:

```
[88577.880874] sd 38:0:0:0: [sdh] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=3s
[88577.880889] sd 38:0:0:0: [sdh] tag#5 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[88577.880893] sd 38:0:0:0: [sdh] tag#5 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[88577.880897] sd 38:0:0:0: [sdh] tag#5 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 54 25 88 8f 00 02 00 00
[88577.880900] critical medium error, dev sdh, sector 1411745935 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 64 prio class 2
```

From all I've read that is a sign that the disk isn't doing too well and I'm not too worried about that.

But what surprises me is that the `rsync` I use to copy the data (mostly big files like disk images, ISOs, ...) doesn't seem to report most of these error.

The current `rsync` invocation has been running for more than an hour. In that time I saw dozens of those error messages in `dmesg`. But all the while `rsync` reported just 2 I/O errors:

```
$ rsync -rlt --no-i-r --info=progress2 /mnt/olddisk/somedir /mnt/target
 47,316,611,088   5%   34.36MB/s    0:21:53 (xfr#26, to-chk=754/787)
rsync: [sender] read errors mapping "/mnt/oldisk/somedir/dir1/chunkyfile1.bin": Input/output error (5)
148,137,878,449  15%   49.70MB/s    0:47:22 (xfr#46, to-chk=734/787)
rsync: [sender] read errors mapping "/mnt/olddisk/somedir/dir2/chunkyfile2.bin": Input/output error (5)
206,615,147,043  22%   55.38MB/s    3:32:44  xfr#61, to-chk=719/787)
```

What I'm wondering is this: are those "unrecovered" and "critical" errors somehow corrected ? Are they re-attempted and succeed? Is the kernel silently returning wrong/broken/empty read results to `rsync` while swallowing the fact that an I/O error happened?

To the best of my knowledge no other process is interacting with the source drive.

The source disk is formatted with boring old ext4, so I don't think there's any error correction codes embedded in that data.

Does it matter that the disk is attached via an external SATA dock and connected via USB? I know that this can be a source of problems, but given that the errors specifically mention "Medium Error" I suspect they are related to the actual happenings in the disk rather than the communication to the rest of my system.

Comment: For peace of mind you can look up which file contains the block in error on
sdh by
using `debugfs` and its commands `icheck` to find the inode of the file,
and `ncheck` to find the filename of the inode. See
[example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37243/119298) script, replacing
the `BADBLOCKS="$(dumpe2fs...` line with a list to check eg
`BADBLOCKS='1411745935 ...'.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite possible that some reads were reattempted. And this might be done on several levels of the software.
There is one more thing: read-ahead. The kernel might (should) request more that it actually needs, so the errors may be reported and forgotten. And subsequent request is not satisfied from the cache, as it would be, so the reading is done again. (On top of that, the disk itself may read more than requested or doing some sanity checks and report that to the kernel?)

Comment: Hm ... that's possible, I still find it weird. I ended up having 5 files (out of many hundreds) fail to transfer while seeing dozens of error messages like above in dmesg ... Anyway, I'm glad that most of the data is off that disk now. Unfortunately there are no checksums with the files so I don't know if there was any "silent" data corruption.

Comment: You may read whole drive again and compare the results, something like  `find /mnt/firstdisk -type f | while read x; do y="${x#\/mnt\/firstdisk}/mnt/other}"; cmp "$x" "$y" || { echo "$x" different or failed >> logfile; z=/third/"$(dirname "$x")"; mkdir -p "$z"; cp "$x" "$z"/"$(basename "$x" ; }; done`  or similar, to get some info and maybe salvage a tiny fraction of remaining files.

Comment: And you can gain some more observation by executing (repeatedly)  `dd if=/dev/oldhdd of=/dev/zero`. You may even specify numbers of block you want to read and/or safe the parts or the whole  by of=file.